# Unable to add plugin to Cardova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm getting an issue with the Cordova [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) application. 
I'm currently using version 3.4 of Cordova and I'm unable to add a plugin to Cordova.

While running only Cordova in Eclipse or Android Studio, it is throwing an error:

> Cordova activity not found.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here's how you create a Cordova Project (We never know)

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Then, go into the project folder and type this:

```
cordova plugin add your-plugin
```

Of course, this has to be written directly in a console, I don't think you could do this from Eclipse or Android Studio.

Read this document again if you have doubts : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Thankyou for your early your replay, i am using cordova since 7 months and am developing an application, i am using console to create cordova project and add plugins, earlier everything is working good. now we are able to add any plugin to our project using console it is getting downloaded properly but while running it is showing errors in the android studio and eclipse. i need the solution here. is there any issue with the 3.4 now.